# Quicksilver goes straight to text-entry mode

Tags: quicksilver

On my old-ish MacBook Pro (pre-unibody), Quicksilver has been misbehaving for quite some time. I fire the keyboard command to launch it (I like command-space, replacing Spotlight), and it comes up in text-entry mode rather than selection mode. I can hit escape and QS closes, but nothing I can do makes it come up prepared to navigate the objects it knows about.

It used to work just great. But it's a waste of cycles right now because it's completely unable to function as what it does.

I've re-launched it, I've deleted and re-installed it. Nothing seems to help.

Comment: What do you mean with "deleted quicksilver" ? Did you just put it in the Trash ?

Comment: And emptied, yes.

Comment: For a reinstall to accomplish anything, you may need to delete some related quicksilver settings/preference files.  You can track them down by hand (~/Library/Application Support and ~/Library/Preferences are good places to look) or use an app (like AppZapper or anything here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/470/how-do-i-uninstall-a-program-completely-on-a-mac)

Answer (score 2):

If I recall, there's a QS trigger called something like "Command Window In Text Mode."  Go to Quicksilver>Triggers>Quicksilver, I think, and look at what triggers are enabled.

Another possibility is that you have the "Spacebar Behavior" set to "Switch to text mode" in Quicksilver>Preferences>Command, and this is getting triggered when you use cmd-space.  It shouldn't matter, but it's worth a look.