# How can I remove Firefox using terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, firefox

I'm a beginner with Mac OS X. Would somebody please tell me how to fully uninstall Firefox using Terminal on Mac OS X Lion?

I'm experiencing hangs and crashes with Firefox 5.0.1, so I want to remove it then re-install it.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove Firefox.app:

- Login with an administrator account
- `sudo rm -rf /Applications/Firefox.app/`

You get the same result by just dragging the Firefox app from /Applications/ to the trash.

If the crashes continue after reinstalling, deleting preferences and support files in the user library may help:

- `~/Library/Preferences/org.mozilla.firefox*`
- `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox`
- `~/Library/Application Support/Mozilla`
- `~/Library/Mozilla`
- `~/Library/Caches/Firefox`

Comment: please can you list me those files when you get back home

Comment: @JAHelia, you could use a program like [AppCleaner](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/471/1453) to do the search & deletion for you.

Answer (score 2):

It's very probable that your profile is corrupt, rather than Firefox itself (in which case, deleting Firefox won't help as any new installation will use the corrupt profile).

Creating a new profile may help - the safest way to do that is using the [Profile Manager](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing-profiles).

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider uninstalling it using [AppZapper](http://www.appzapper.com/), which will remove the app and all of its configuration files.  There is a fully-functional free trial available.