# How do I properly uninstall Kensington TrackballWorks from OSX Lion?

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I uninstall a program completely on a Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/470/how-do-i-uninstall-a-program-completely-on-a-mac)

Kensington's TrackballWorks software does not seem to come with an uninstaller component, and is not compatible with my Kensington trackball model. Accordingly, I'd like to uninstall it. Can anyone tell me how to properly (thoroughly) uninstall this software from my OSX Lion installation?

Comment: I'm closing this since there's already a canonical 'How can I properly uninstall an app?' question. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: I understand the explanation for why my question was closed, but another recent one (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34381/how-can-i-uninstall-adobe-air-on-lion) is still open and has answers; what is the important difference between my question and the other?

Comment: The difference to me is that AIR is a framework, not an app. Frameworks work differently than plain apps, and the methods listed in the answer for removing an app aren't guaranteed to work.

Comment: That's a very good point. Thank-you. As it was, I looked in the BOM for the TrackballWorks software to find all the things it installed and noticed that it did, in fact, provide an uninstaller. So, either way I would be able to clean up everything it left (either by removing everything listed in its BOM, or just using the uninstaller app).