# How can I uninstall Adobe Air on Lion?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to uninstall Adobe Air on Lion.

All of my air apps won't load so I think an uninstall/reinstall will help.

I've opened the Adobe AIR uninstaller but nothing comes up.  I can't figure out how to do this.

Does anyone know how I can uninstall Adobe Air?

Comment: Was it installed under Lion, or under a previous OS that was subsequently upgraded?

Comment: I would try a reinstall first: http://get.adobe.com/air/ If that doesn't fix it outright, then see if you can uninstall it. If anything, a reinstallation should let you subsequently uninstall. Then reboot and reinstall again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To uninstall AdobeAIR by hand, quit any unnecessary applications (specially applications that might use AdobeAIR). Then delete the following files and folders.

*/Applications/Adobe/Flash Player/AddIns/airappinstaller* (alternatively remove the */Applications/Adobe* folder - first checking that its sub-folders do not contain files other than AdobeAIR files.)

*/Applications/Utilities/Adobe AIR Application Installer.app*

*/Applications/Utilities/Adobe AIR Uninstaller.app*

*/Library/Frameworks/Adobe AIR.framework*

*/Users/Shared/Library/Application Support/Adobe/AIR* (alternatively remove the */Users/Shared/Library* folder - first checking that its sub-folders do not contain files other than AdobeAIR files.)

The following files are in your Home Folder (represented by '~'). You can access this Library folder by holding down <kbd>⌥</kbd> while accessing the **Finder** menu **Go > Library**.

*~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/AIR* (alternatively remove the *~/Library/Application Support/Adobe* folder - first checking that its sub-folders do not contain files other than AdobeAIR files.)

*~/Library/Caches/com.adobe.air.ApplicationInstaller*

*~/Library/Caches/com.adobe.air.Installer*

*~/Library/Preferences/com.adobe.air.ApplicationInstaller.plist*

*~/Library/Preferences/com.adobe.air.ApplicationInstaller.plist.lockfile*

*~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/#Security/FlashPlayerTrust/air.1.0.trust.cfg*

*~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/www.macromedia.com/bin/airappinstaller*

These files were found by scanning the file system before and after installing the latest version of AdobeAIR to see the file changes that were made.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

- Open Finder and navigate to the following directory: HD > Library >
  Framework
- Delete the following folder: Â Adobe AIR.framework
- Download and run [Adobe Air Installer](http://get.adobe.com/air), and it should work.

This is courtesy of the this site [here](http://www.iakmal.com/how-to-adobe-air-uninstallation-fix-full-guide-for-mac-and-pc-users-1126/). Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now, but I'll as soon as I get back home on my Mac. So, it's just a wild guess...

Download it again and install the freshly downloaded package. It will either ask you to overwrite your previous installed package or offer you a way to uninstall the previous versions.