# NoSleep still in in settings though uninstalled?

Tags: settings, bug

I have still the NoSleep options in my settings panel although it's fully uninstalled. How can I remove them, too? System is 10.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right clicking the NoSleep options button from the main screen of System Preferences and click the "Remove Preference Pane" option.

Answer (score 3):

Download NoSleep.dmg or use it if already there. Mount it and click "Uninstall.command".  Reopen preferences, it should be gone.

Uninstalling using official methods is preferred over simply deleting the app packages. Two old, but still relevant questions:

- [Why there is no standard way to uninstall programs in MacOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43768/why-there-is-no-standard-way-to-uninstall-programs-in-macos)
- [How do I uninstall a program completely on a Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/470/how-do-i-uninstall-a-program-completely-on-a-mac?noredirect=1&lq=1)