# How to stop MS AutoUpdate prompt

Tags: macbook-pro, microsoft, auto-update

So far as I know, I don't have any Microsoft applications on my MacBook Air. I had installed Microsoft Teams in the past, which I later uninstalled by dragging the app to the trash (after I first saw this prompt) as it wasn't in use. Still, I get the 'Microsoft AutoUpdate' prompt often.

How do I get rid of this permanently?

[image: Microsoft autoupdate]

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-office-for-mac-eefa1199-5b58-43af-8a3d-b73dc1a8cae3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/troubleshoot-office-for-mac-issues-by-completely-uninstalling-before-you-reinstall-ec3aa66e-6a76-451f-9d35-cba2e14e94c0

Comment: How do you uninstall properly? By the way, the prompt showed up when MS team was there already.

Comment: As in the above links, There are files here and there. They need to be removed.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/43770/313842

Comment: @ankiiiiiii, I removed the directories too. But I am not sure if it will stop that prompt. It hasn't shown up yet again since I removed directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is provided by Microsoft AutoUpdate.
You can disable the message without removing AU by setting the following key:

```
defaults write com.microsoft.autoupdate2.plist \
    AcknowledgedDataCollectionPolicy RequiredDataOnly
```

https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2019/07/23/suppressing-microsoft-autoupdates-required-data-notice-screen/

To completely remove AU from your system, delete the following:

- `/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/MAU2.0/`
- `~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft AutoUpdate/`
- `~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.autoupdate2.plist`
- `~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.autoupdate.fba.plist`
- `/Library/LaunchAgents/com.microsoft.update.agent.plist`

Comment: Is it safe to remove it completely? 
There is one folder in `~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft AU Daemon/`. What is it with that folder?

Comment: @Kishor I don't have a folder, just a tiny database with 2 rows containing metadata of last update times etc.

Comment: Yes.  I removed that folder too. I am afraid of Microsoft's update, that too on Mac.