# Does deleting Mac App Store apps in Launchpad delete related files in the Library folders too?

Tags: mac-appstore, launchpad, applications

When I delete Mac App Store apps in Launchpad, does it delete related files in the Library folders too? I mean files like preferences, application support files etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried uninstalling some applications, and files in these folders or the corresponding folders in `~/Library/Containers/` were sometimes deleted and sometimes not:

- `~/Library/Caches/` (deleted for most applications)
- `~/Library/Application Support/`

Files in these folders weren't deleted for any of the applications I tested with:

- `~/Library/Preferences/`
- `~/Library/Saved Application State/`
- `/var/db/receipts/`
- `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/`
- `~/Library/Application Support/CrashReporter/`
- `~/Library/Caches/com.plausiblelabs.crashreporter.data/`
- `~/Library/Application Support/Growl/Tickets/`

For example Kindle books or the database for notes in JustNotes were not deleted.

You can see what files are accessed by uninstalld with `sudo opensnoop -n uninstalld` and search for support files with `mdfind $(osascript -e 'id of app "AppName"')`. If you want to uninstall applications more completely, it's probably safe to just delete the whole sandbox containers in `~/Library/Containers/`.

Comment: Maybe Apple records which one of the two contradictions is respected by developers of an app, then `uninstalld` refers to that record when evaluating whether it's acceptable to remove application support data. It's not acceptable to remove user data.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This helps me understand the system better. So what gets removed is the decision of the developers? :-)

Comment: Advice in the Mac Developer Library is somewhat contradictory. Emphasis added by me … Application Support [**CAN** include files that contain user data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/MacOSXDirectories/MacOSXDirectories.html) (2012-03-08); and
[files should be app-specific but should **NEVER** store user data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/AppRuntime/AppRuntime.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH2-SW9) (2012-07-23).

Comment: @GrahamPerrin Sorry, I forgot to post a comment after rolling back your edit. I think "user data" can mean both documents that would normally be opened by the user and something like SQLite files.

Comment: @Lri no problem, the content was easily replaced as a comment. As an example, I never liked Microsoft's use of `~/Documents` for *databases* of user data (for Outlook etc.); `~/Library/Application Support` seemed more appropriate. I still don't like to find databases – not human readable – amongst my readable documents. If Apple's guidance to developers is changing, I wonder about the motivation. Maybe WWDC 2012 videos, or other developer documentation, will hold clues. Meantime, my first guess is that future plans for iCloud play a part.