# How can I hide / remove updates from the Mac App Store?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I installed an app, didn't like it, and then moved it from Applications to the Trash and emptied the trash. Now when I go into the App Store, I am stil being prompted to update the application even though it has been removed.

[image]

I tried searching the hard drive and I don't see any other copies of the Application.

I also tried running this command which is supposed to update the database of what is actually installed on the system for the App Store:

```
sudo /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

It is still showing up. How can I get rid of it?

On a related note, I accidentally hid another update that I wanted to install by right clicking on it and choosing "Hide Update". I was not able to hide Clyppan which is the app I'm trying to ditch - but if you do accidentally hide something you want to install, how do you get it back?

[image]

Comment: I am having the same problem with the app 'IP Scanner". I had it installed on my computer, then did a clean install of the OS and for some reason it kept giving me this update even though I haven't installed it since the OS reinstall. Anyone figured out how to fix this?

Also, why can some updates be hidden and not others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it still show up in Launchpad? Or have you tried downloading the application again and removing it from Launchpad? It runs [uninstalld](https://superuser.com/questions/319782/os-x-lion-what-is-uninstalld), which doesn't normally remove many [other files than the application bundle](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58960/3936), but it probably makes some other changes.

Comment: This is a good thought. I tried it but I didn't have any luck. I also did a sudo find command from Terminal and searched the entire hard drive but did not find it anywhere. Is there any way to track down what is making it show up?

Comment: Does `mdfind clyppan` still return some support files?

Comment: hmm - yes it does! Ok I just removed those files and then ran the above `lsregister` command. it still leaves `/private/var/db/receipts/cc.omh.Clyppan.bom` and `/private/var/db/receipts/cc.omh.Clyppan.plist` behind though. and the app is still showing up in the updates section even after restarting the app store and doing `killall storeagent`

Comment: moi @Lauri Ranta - any more thoughts?

Comment: I don't know. You could try removing it from `/Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist`.

Comment: Or [rebuilding the Spotlight index](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65525/how-do-i-stop-macappstore-from-showing-updates-for-deleted-apps).

Comment: I tried removing it and rebuilding the spotlight index and one of them worked! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an external drive attached to your mac? There might be a copy of that app on that drive (eg if it were a backup or clone of your main drive).

Alternatively, try going to the 'Purchases' tab, find that app in the list, and right-click > Hide Purchase... and see if that stops it from showing up in the Updates list.

From the Mac App Store help, to see hidden purchases do this:

> To view hidden apps, choose Store > View My Account, enter your Apple ID and password, click View Account, and then click View Hidden Purchases. To show a hidden app in the purchased apps list, click its Unhide button

Comment: Hmm, I tried all of these without any luck. +1 for helping me figure out how to unhide hidden purchases.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with an App Store update for 'PDFScanner'. The app was somehow left on a hard drive after a clean upgrade to Yosemite. It started appearing in App Store under upgrades, although a Spotlight could not find the original app.

I did:

1. Finder → Go → Go to Folder
2. In the field typed: `/Library`
3. When it opened, I entered in a search field PDFScanner" and the app was there!
4. With Option+click, dragged it to the Trash.
5. Voila! No more red dot 'Upgrade PDFScanner'!

Answer (score -1):

just follow these instructions...
it worked for me.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2409

---

Spotlight: How to re-index folders or volumes

From the Apple () menu, choose System Preferences.
Click Spotlight.
Click the Privacy tab.
Drag a folder or an entire volume (your hard drive) to the list.
If prompted for confirmation, click OK.
Remove the item or volume you just added to the list by clicking it and then clicking the minus ("-") button.
Close Spotlight preferences.
Spotlight will re-index the contents of the folder or volume.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.