# Deleting an update downloaded from App Store that is not installed

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update, notifications

I now run OS X 10.9.5 on my office laptop, which is monitored by my company. App Store alerted me about Yosemite, and I chose to download and install it. After download completed, I got a notification saying that my company does not support Yosemite and the installation was terminated.

Now Yosemite shows up in App Store as "DOWNLOADED" as shown below, and I get notification asking me to install it every day. How can I remove the downloaded file and/or stop receiving this notification?

[image]

Comment: talk to your IT department - they control your machine's profile

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the comment. I actually want to delete the downloaded files locally and don't plan to install it anymore.

Comment: I can't test, as I have nothing DL'ing right now, but the intermediate location is apparently ~/Library/Application Support/App Store/ Once fully downloaded, they go to Applications  As far as the notification itself, in App Store, I think you're stuck with that - I was, til I bit the bullet.

Comment: Then the problem becomes there's nothing but updatejournal.plist lying in this folder...

Comment: The Yosemite file is in your Applications folder, named Install OS X Yosemite.app You can delete it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry I didn't fully get "Once fully downloaded, they go to Applications" just now. Problem solved. Thank you.

Comment: Most welcome...

Comment: [Does this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/65708/5472) solve your situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to Install Yosemite.

In your case just open the Applications folder navigate to the "Install OS X Yosemite.app" and Delete it.