# No X button on App Store downloaded apps icons in Launchpad "jiggle mode"

Tags: macos, applications, mac-appstore, launchpad

I can't seem to uninstall Mac App Store purchased applications.

I know **that holding down the Option key or clicking and holding on the app icon** to make the icons start **jiggling** so you can uninstall the app by clicking the “X” shown in the corner of icons only works for apps downloaded from the Mac App Store.

But I my case, **not even apps downloaded from the Mac App Store show the "X" button** when in jiggle mode.

Has anyone experienced the same problem ? How did you solved it ?

UPDATE:
When I delete the app from the Finder, the app's icon remains in the launcher, undeletabe, only it doesn't find the missing app.

Comment: When you delete the app in the Finder, you actually move it to the trash can. It isn't gone until the trash is emptied. Does the file disappear from Launchpad when you empty the trash?

Comment: @DanielLawson Thanks, when I emptied thw trash the icon finally disappeared. Do you have any idea why the "X" icon  doesn't appear while in jiggle mode preventing to me from deleting the app from the very launchpad as expected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use Launchpad to remove applications. Just deleting the application bundle is still a supported way to remove or uninstall an application. If you also want to remove settings or cache files, delete the directory in `~/Library/Containers/`. App Store applications are not allowed to install kernel extensions or preference panes, and any executables for helper processes are inside the application bundle and not in an Application Support directory.

When you remove an application from Launchpad, it is "uninstalled" by using uninstalld from Uninstall.framework, but in practice that only removes some support files (like `~/Library/Containers/*/Data/Library/Caches/`) addition to the application bundle. Other support files like preferences files or sometimes even sqlite files for user data are not removed. See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58959/does-deleting-mac-app-store-apps-in-launchpad-delete-related-files-in-the-librar/58960#58960).

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why "X" button doesn't show even for apps downloaded from the Mac App Store ?

Comment: I believe Launchpad does not support deleting items from the Mac App Store because deleting them requires authentication, and Launchpad does not seem to support such feature just yet.

Comment: @BrunoPhilipe The remove buttons are shown for App Store applications on my installation of 10.8. When I press one of them, the application bundle is deleted by `uninstalld`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset the Launchpad database, it’ll rebuild all your installed apps and sort them by name.

```
[ -e ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db ] && rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db && killall Dock
```

Uninstalling apps from Mac App Store can always be done through Finder. Cleaning the app settings, caches, and related files requires third party apps such as CleanMyMac, AppCleaner, or AppZapper.

Comment: Those third party apps will not always remove all the related files

Comment: Mark, I have to vouch for AppZapper. It **always** remove associated files. It shows you exactly which files it will remove, such as preferences and plists.

Comment: @Mark it’s true that third party doesn’t always remove all related files. Sometimes I also need to hunt them down by using **find** command in Terminal. But, most of times, those apps do the job well for apps installed without package manager.

Answer (score 0):

You mention holding down the option key - I've never done it this way. You can hold down the mouse button when selecting an icon in the Launchpad to get the icons 'jiggling,' at which point the 'x' should appear. Give that a shot.

Comment: Yes, holding option and holding the mouse button over the app icon are equivalent, they both activate the "jiggle mode". The X doesn't appear for me either way.