# How do I completely uninstall an app in OS X without the use of a dedicated app eg AppZapper?

Tags: applications, macos

I came across this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/470/how-do-i-uninstall-a-program-completely-on-a-mac), however all the answers recommend using Applications eg [AppZapper](http://appzapper.com/) or [similar](http://alternativeto.net/software/appzapper/?platform=mac) to achieve the uninstallation of the App desired.

What are the steps required where the uninstallation is carried out by "manual means" by the user to achieve complete uninstallation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general most programs place files within the App icon, which is really a special folder for the Applications files. Many also add files within the Application Support folder within your library.

Simply drag the Application icon to the trash, and empty it. Then open your Library folder (you might have to click on the "Go" menu item in Finder, while also holding down he Option key to expose the Library). Look under the Application Support folder, and see if your Application has a folder, which you may also trash. You can also do a general search in this folder for the App name or Software company name.

Of course some apps also put other files in other places, such as LaunchAgents, PreferencePanes and other folders, but that is where such apps as AppZapper and AppCleaner are very nice to have. Also, check the Application website, as often software vendors publish the details of where they install data within OSX, usually in an item called 'manual uninstall'.

Comment: Also this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efnXbn1nC4E seems to complement your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any external tools:

The Apple way-->move to trash and you are done.

That can leave residue but not very relevant files.

Some app come with uninstaller (since they files are intertwined in the OS.

Some app you open the "Show Package Content" so you see what came with the package.

- Not so recommended methods (you could make a fatal mistake)- the Terminal!

You could drill down using terminal and find residues using the "mdfind".

You could drill in to the System Library and delete manually.

**It’s dangerously easy to delete files with the `rm` command** do not use unless you are 101% sure, it can not be reversed.

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps you may want to take:

- remove any support files in /Library
- remove any support files in ~/Library
- remove any installed kernel extensions
- remove any cache files left in /LibraryCaches
- remove any cache files left in ~/LibraryCaches
- Generically: remove any file created by the application at installation or during its run time.

To answer the question **I think** you want answered: there is no built-in facility to remove all traces of an app that you wish to uninstall (which is why programs like AppZapper exist at all).

Answer (score -1):

Simply delete the application from the list of applications. There is no "uninstall" like Windows.

Comment: Not always true. Some apps install for example launchd/kexts etc.