# How to uninstall USB to VGA Adapter's drivers?

Tags: driver, macos

About a year ago I bought a USB to VGA Adapter from Insignia (https://www.insigniaproducts.com/pdp/NS-PUV308/6138366). I no longer use this Adapter and would like to remove the drivers because sometimes the drivers can use up to 70% of CPU, but can't find a way to remove the drivers.

Comment: What have you tried to far? Is there an uninstaller in the DMG with the driver?

Comment: I didn't think about an uninstaller... I found the uninstaller. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I uninstall a program completely on a Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/470/how-do-i-uninstall-a-program-completely-on-a-mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually drivers come with an uninstaller. Redownload the installation package/dmg of the driver if necessary and use the uninstaller included there.

---

In the specific case, the driver can be redownloaded from the web site linked in the question.

[image]

It contains both an installer and an uninstaller. From looking at it, the following files get removed

```
/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/MCTT6Audio.driver
/Library/Extensions/MCTTrigger2.kext
/Library/Extensions/MCTTrigger6USB.kext
/Library/Extensions/MCTTriggerGraphics.plugin
/Library/Extensions/Trigger5Core.kext
/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mct.USBVGASync.plist
/Library/LaunchDaemons/tw.com.mct.TriggerDriver.plist
/System/Library/Extensions/MCTTrigger2.kext
/System/Library/Extensions/MCTTrigger6USB.kext
/System/Library/Extensions/MCTTriggerGraphics.plugin
/System/Library/Extensions/Trigger5Core.kext
/System/Library/Services/USBVGASync
/usr/local/libexec/MCTTriggerDriver
/usr/local/sbin/USBVGASync
```

After removing the files a restart is required.